# classPath spark.jobserver. not found

Tags: scala, curl, apache-spark, spark-jobserver

I have added a new code file along with the existing example files in the [spark-jobserver directory](https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver/tree/master/job-server-tests/src/main/scala/spark/jobserver) and created a .jar. It throws the following error even after the jar file is uploaded successfully.

```
F:\Soft\spark\Projects\spark-jobserver-master_1\spark-jobserver-master>curl --data-binary @job-server-tests/target/scala-2.10/job-server-tests_2.10-0.7.1-SNAPSHOT.jar localhost:8090/jars/test
{
  "status": "SUCCESS",
  "result": "Jar uploaded"
}
F:\Soft\spark\Projects\spark-jobserver-master_1\spark-jobserver-master>curl -d "input.string = SamsungJ7Prime16GBGold" "localhost:8090/jobs?appName=test&classPath=spark.jobserver.ViewsRecommender"
{
  "status": "ERROR",
  "result": "classPath spark.jobserver.ViewsRecommender not found"
}
```

Though the above command fails, when I call another class from the same jar it runs successfully as shown below,

```
F:\Soft\spark\Projects\spark-jobserver-master_1\spark-jobserver-master>curl -d "input.string = a b c a b see" "localhost:8090/jobs?appName=test&classPath=spark.jobserver.WordCountExample"
{
  "duration": "Job not done yet",
  "classPath": "spark.jobserver.WordCountExample",
  "startTime": "2017-04-14T16:04:17.480+05:30",
  "context": "1ab9cf56-spark.jobserver.WordCountExample",
  "status": "STARTED",
  "jobId": "d177eefb-0642-442a-a650-9c0a07ad6400"
}
```

I have [raised an issue in the github repository](https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver/issues/797) and attached the .jar file.

Comment: Ensure that the jar has the class.

Comment: @noorul, I unzipped the jar and checked it. It has the class.

Comment: Can you look at job server log for any clue?